# How to solve Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value with Xcode

Tags: ios, option-type, fatal-error

I would like to know and learn to solve this kind of the problem.

It keeps telling me that

**Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var A1: UIButton!

var player_turn = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func A1_(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if  player_turn % 2 == 0 {
            A1.setImage(UIImage(named:"King_side.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            A1.setImage(UIImage(named:"Queen_side.png"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to connect your `A1` outlet to a button in your storyboard or XIB.

In general for that kind of error message, take a look at [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu?rq=1).